# Fragment resets when switch between Fragments on bottom Navigation

Tags: android, fragment

I have 5 Fragments and controlled by Bottom Navigation.
When I apply any changes in one Fragment after that I click on other Fragment when I come back again to first Fragment I feel that Fragment restarts and there is no change that I have applied before and resets.
I want to keep that changes on switch fragments.
How Can I Solve this problem?

Comment: What kind of changes? kinldy specify and add what you have done till now.

Comment: Please share your code. It will be more useful for everybody.